# How to pass some parameters to the default rendering method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, rendering

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to pass some parameters to the default rendering method. That is, if I have a code like

```
def show
  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # This, by default, renders the 'show.html.erb' file
   end
end
```

I would like to pass some parameters, maybe like (note: the following doesn't work)

```
def show
  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    # Here I would like to add some local objects that will be available in the 'show.html.erb' template file
    format.html { render ..., :locals => { :content => { :value => 'Sample value' } } }
   end
end
```

so that in the `show.html.erb` template I can make something like:

```
<%=
  content[:value]
  # => 'Sample value'
%>
```

In few words, *I would like to pass parameter values in the same way as made for partial template rendering related to the `:locals` key*:

```
render :partial, 
       :locals => {
          :content => { :value => 'Sample value' }
       }
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do exactly what you described.  I looked it up here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render under the heading "Rendering a template" and gave it a whirl myself.  You learn something new everyday.

You can simply do

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :locals => { :content => { :value => 'Sample value' } } }
  end
end
```

I would consider why you need to do this instead of using instance variables.  Maybe there is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

How about setting an *instance variable*?

```
# your_controller.rb

def show
  @content_value = ...
end
```

```
# show.html.erb

<%= @content_value %>
```

Comment: I think that the approach described in the question (maybe) is better than that proposed by you... there is any reason to do that as you proposed? What do you advice about?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we're working with actions `show.html.erb` is an `action` view rather than a `partial` view, we're passing parameters via instance variables on the controller such as

```
def show
  ...
  @foo = "bar"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
   end
end
```

Now in the `app/views/foos/show.html.erb` file, we have access to `@foo`.

When rendering partials, there are a few ways to pass parameters:

This will render partial `app/views/foos/_foo.html.erb` by default because it knows `@foo` is of type `Foo`.  In it, you will have access to a `foo` variable automatically.

```
<%= render @foo %>
```

Here we will render `app/views/foos/_foo_details.html.erb`, and pass in an object. The object takes the name of the partial, so inside `_foo_details.html.erb` we'll have access to a variable called `foo_details`.

```
<%= render :partial => "foo_details", :object => @foo %>
```

Finally, and mostly related to your question, we'll render a partial called `_foo_things.html.erb` and pass it some locals.  In this case, you'd get a local variable called `title` which you could work with.

```
<%= render :partial => "foo_things", :locals => {:title=> "Test 123"} %>
```

I hope that answers your question.